# Security implications of mount --bind in a chroot environment

Tags: security, chroot, jail

Assume you have a *chroot* environment where you need a resource - an application or a library - which resides on the host (external to the chroot).

Which are the security implications (if any) of performing a `mount --bind` (from the host to the chroot) on that resource rather than installing it on the chroot - i.e. via an `apt-get install` -?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I see it both a `mount --bind` of a directory and a hard link of a file share the same security problem: files in the chroot end up being *the same* (that is, pointing to the same inode) than files outside the chroot. So if the chroot user finds a way to modify these files inside the chroot they've essentially found a way to modify *your* files.

This may or may not be a serious security issue depending on the environment you're setting up, but you have to take it into account when making this choice.